# how I can split the lines of the dataframe, consider "\ n" as a separator

Tags: python

My dataframe:(i have only one column)

```py
0  \nSanofi\nFrance\nSanté\n99,77\n59,93\n
1  \nBP\nRoyaume-Uni\nEnergie\n98,39\n124,12\n
2  \nNovartis\nSuisse\nSanté\n146,29\n101,15\n
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input dataframe- `df` and the column in question - `x`:

```py
res=df["x"].str.split(r"\n", expand=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

  0         1            2        3       4       5 6
0      Sanofi       France    Santé   99,77   59,93
1          BP  Royaume-Uni  Energie   98,39  124,12
2    Novartis       Suisse    Santé  146,29  101,15
```

Comment: Error: dataframe has no attribute'split'

Comment: You want to split them into separate columns?

Comment: yess exactly :)

Comment: Gotcha :) have a look at my edit

Answer (score 1):

You should upload some reproducible code. But this is trivial to do with the split function in python.

```
elem = '0 \nSanofi\nFrance\nSanté\n99,77\n59,93\n 1 \nBP\nRoyaume-Uni\nEnergie\n98,39\n124,12\n 2 \nNovartis\nSuisse\nSanté\n146,29\n101,15\n'

thing = elem.split('\n')
print(thing)
```

Which outputs a list like this:

```
['0 ', 'Sanofi', 'France', 'Santé', '99,77', '59,93', ' 1 ', 'BP', 'Royaume-Uni', 'Energie', '98,39', '124,12', ' 2 ', 'Novartis', 'Suisse', 'Santé', '146,29', '101,15', '']
```

Comment: Error: dataframe has no attribute'split'